# Have the code in javascript but no HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code with the help of someone here, in order to print two different styles..
The issue is i have the script in javascript but not the html, please help me

```
function print(o) {
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].innerHTML;
    if (o == 'client') {
        head += '<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css" media="screen, projection,print" />';
    }
    if (o == 'member') {
        head += '<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style1.css" media="screen, projection,print" />';
    }
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].innerHTML = head;
}
```

So, how should the HTML be?
It's supposed to be 2 buttons or something...
Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: I mean, i don't know how to make a html in order for the function to work..

Comment: Very much depends on what you're trying to do, we cannot really find it out... do you know what you're trying to do?

Comment: Yes, sure, so i'm trying to print with different stylesheets.. so if you click one button it appends one css, if you click the other it appens the other css

Comment: I don't know how to do it.. i mean, is hould have two buttons which print different styles... that's all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<htmL>
<head>
<script>
  window.onload = function () {
     print("client");
  };

  function print(o) {
         var head  = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
         var link  = document.createElement('link');
         link.rel  = 'stylesheet';
         link.type = 'text/css';
         if (o == 'client') {
           link.href = 'css/style1.css';
         }
         if (o == 'member') {
           link.href = 'css/style2.css';
         }

         link.media = 'screen, projection,print';
         head.appendChild(link);
 }
 </script>
  </head>
  <body>
   <input type="button" name="clientStyle" value="Client Style" onclick="print('client');">
   <input type="button" name="memberStyle" value="Member Style" onclick="print('member');">
  </body>
  </html>
```

May be.. do you want like this...? Please

Comment: Yes but please, could you help me witht he html part? i need two links, with client and member!

Comment: @pyetjegoo check..my edit..

Comment: Thanks..i guess it's the issue of the javascript function..it's not really working..

Comment: @pyetjegoo this may help u...

Comment: Thanks Rishi but still won't trigger anya ction..

Comment: @pyetjegoo its.. working dude... if want i can give my sample workout files..!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25762/discussion-between-rishi-php-and-pyetjegoo)

Answer (score 2):

For example this HTML should work with your code:

```
<button onclick="print('client')">Client</button>
<button onclick="print('member')">Member</button>
```

By the way, you are redefining browser native `print` function.

*UPD*. You just need a way to invoke your `print` function with the parameter (`client` or `member`). You can attach this behaviour to any HTML element, just add an `onclick` attribute to it (this is the simplest way). E.g to links:

```
<a onclick="print('client')">Client</a>
<a onclick="print('member')">Member</a>
```

Comment: Can you please explain better, and could i just change them into links? the buttons?

Comment: The function is not really working..could you help me with the javascript please?

Comment: Yes, well, i used this part:
<a href="#" onclick="print('client')">Client</a>
The issue is it's not printing...

Comment: What should it print?